# Eloquent ORM select com relação belongToMany

Tags: php, laravel-eloquent

Tabela Usuario

```
usuarioid | nome
 1        | joão
 2        | jose
 3        | maria
```

Tabela Rede

```
redeid | nome
 1     | Subway
 2     | McDonald's
 3     | Burguer King
```

Tabela Rede_Usuario

```
id | redeid | usuarioid
 1 |    1   |    2
 2 |    2   |    1
 2 |    2   |    3
 3 |    3   |    3
```

o usuario pode listar apenas os usuarios que fazem parte da mesma rede que ele, preciso de um select assim:

```
SELECT 
      usuario.* 
INNER JOIN 
      rede on rede.redeid = rede_usuario.redeid 
INNER JOIN 
      rede_usuario on rede_usuario.usuarioid = usuario.usuarioid
WHERE 
      usuario.usuarioid = ? and rede.redeId in (?, ?)
```

tentei montar dessa forma com o eloquent:

```
Usuario::select('usuario.*')
         ->where('usuarioid','2')// usuario maria passou o id do jose (2)
         ->with(['rede' => function( $query ) {
                $query->whereIn('rede.redeId', [2,3])// a rede da maria é 2 e 3
         }])->first();// não deveria retornar infomação do jose (id 2) mas retorna =\
```

mas não deu certo, o usuario **maria** só poderia listar **maria** e **joão**, mas não poderia listar **jose** porque **jose** não faz parte das redes 2 e 3, a query não da erro mas ele lista usuarios fora da sua rede, quando o usuario loga no sistema eu pego a rede dele, então nessa query o usuario informa o id do usuario que ele quer ver e a rede que ele pertence, e só retorna resultado com a regra acima (da mesma rede).

Obs: quando o usuario loga no sistema automaticamente lista apenas os usuarios da rede dele, porem por questão de segurança quero implementar isso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supondo que esteja usando o [Eloquent ORM](https://github.com/illuminate/database), você pode obter a query desejada com joins:

```
$query = DB::table('table')->select('usuario.*')
            ->where('usuarioid','2')
            ->join("rede",function($join){
                $join->on("rede.id","=","rede_usuario.redeid");
            })
            ->join("usuario",function($join){
                $join->on("rede_usuario.usuarioid","=","usuario.usuarioid");
            })->toSql();
```

O resultado da query acima seria:

```
select usuario.* from `table` 
inner join `rede` on `rede`.`id` = `rede_usuario`.`redeid` 
inner join `usuario` on `rede_usuario`.`usuarioid` = `usuario`.`usuarioid` 
where `usuarioid` = ?
```

Comment: estava olhando aqui, o pessoal não recomenda muito o uso do join do eloquent devido a problemas de performance ou ambiguidade, e tambem estou utilizando o relacionamento do eloquent `Usuario::find(1)->redes`, e infelizmente isso não funcionou xD, eu mudei seu `->join('tabela', function())`para `join->('tabela','foreignkey','id')` pra funcionar, mas obrigado pela dica!